# "logs" command is supported only for "json-file" and "journald" logging drivers (got: gcplogs)

Tags: docker, gcloud

I have created google cloud compute instance using docker image

```
gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container serverName \
     --container-image gcr.io/myProject/myContainer
```

Decided to ssh to this container:
First I logged in to this compute instance using ssh

```
gcloud compute --project myProject ssh serverName
```

Then inside compute instance I run:

```
docker exec -it e3e840a8347c  /bin/bash
```

I get

```
Error response from daemon: Container e3e840a8347c is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

Well, I need to look at logs to debug the reason of restarting:

```
docker logs e3e840a8347c
```

and I get:

```
"logs" command is supported only for "json-file" and "journald" logging drivers (got: gcplogs)
```

How to see the logs?
And maybe other advise how to debug container restarting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gcloud beta logging read projects/my-project-name/logs/gcplogs-docker-driver | grep data
```

showed me the required logs from docker's `gcplogs`

And here how I picked up the `projects/my-project-name/logs/gcplogs-docker-driver` name:

```
gcloud logging logs list
```

It shows the list of all possible log names.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation regarding `docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/#options), if the logging driver isn't specified in your `docker run` command, then docker will automatically resort to json files or journald as specified by that last error.

Worry not, because docker documentation also holds [information on exactly how to get gcplogs to work with your container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/). If you want to make gcplogs the default logging service for *all* your containers, find your `daemon.json` file for docker and set the `log-driver` and `log-opt` keys to whatever you need and restart docker. If you don't want to change the default logging service, make sure you set your `docker run` command to include the flag `--log-driver=gcplogs`.

As for the debugging portion, if your containers are restarting then either you passed the `-r` or `--restart` flag (unlikely), or thats coupled with a service you are trying to containerize that isn't correctly working. The best advice really is to get the `docker logs` on the container, see whats going wrong, then try searching the internet to fix it. You can also use `docker inspect containerID/Name` if you need to see a containers configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where Docker is configured to use a log driver that doesn't support reading, you'll need to access logs via the configured logging system.

For example, if you configure Docker to log to syslog, you'd view logs from wherever you have syslog writing the entries.

In the case of the `gcplogs` driver, you can get access to the logs through the  Google Cloud Platform Console Logs Viewer interface when you log in to Google Cloud through your web browser.